# Синонимизировать Unity

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Сейчас в ходу 2 идентичных метки:

[unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity)

[unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)

По идее, первая про [оболочку среды рабочего стола GNOME для Ubuntu](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0))
А вторая про  [Игровой движок](http://unity3d.com/ru/)

Но на деле, разницы между ними нет, их одинаково используют для Unity 3D. Пример поиска [[unity] -[unity3d]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity+-unity3d) - все вопросы по Unity 3D.

Их нужно слить и синонимизировать (сделать Unity3d основной).

Прошу высказывать мнения "за" и "против".

Comment: Вполне за. Оставить Unity3d

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "Вопрос-предложение, описывающий идею новой или изменение существующей функциональности и поведения сайта. Для таких вопросов голоса «за» и «против» обозначают согласие или несогласие с предложением, а не качество или полезность вопроса.". Если вы "за", отметьтесь не в комментариях плиз.

Comment: Да, забыл нажать)) Просто главное чтоб была метка Unity3d, а не Unity. А то unity еще всяко может быть, в линухе например и т.д.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, метки все–таки разные. Одна про [Unity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0)), а другая про [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/ru/). Соглашусь, сейчас метки используются не верно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky даже на enSO они слиты. Unity 3D слишком намного популярнее.

Comment: Выполнил объединение. Как оказалось, у нас уже была метка [tag:unity-ubuntu]. Для избежания проблем в будущем, переименовал её в [tag:ubuntu-unity].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## За объединение меток

---

Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за этот ответ, если вы считаете объединение меток необходимым.

Comment: Ситуация такова, что люди глупые, а обсуждение оболочки гнома — полуонтопик, который имеет к СО мало отношения. Если сейчас исправить все метки, то вопросов с unity банально не останется, метка будет удалена. Разумеется, максимум через месяц метка будет пересоздана, потому что многие не заморачиваются с полным названием (да и "3D" — исторический артефакт, оно и 2D умеет). Хоть я и за идеальную организацию меток, в этом случае сопротивление бесполезно. Кроме того, **есть другие Unity**, например, [Microsoft Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) (DI).

Answer (score 6):

## Против объединения меток, но за наведение порядка

---

Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за этот ответ, если вы считаете объединять метки не следует, а вместо этого необходимо добавить описание к метке [unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) и правильно расставить метки в [текущих вопросах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity).

Comment: Описание, кстати, добавил уже )

Answer (score 1):

## Против объединения меток

---

Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за этот ответ, если вы считаете объединять метки не следует.

Comment: Метки объединять просто так нельзя. Кроме игрового движка Unity - ещё и оболочка рабочего стола. Вместо этого стоит просмотреть текущие использования [tag:unity] и заменить на [tag:unity3d] там, где необходимо.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, я как раз про это писал в комментарии к ответу.

Comment: А много ли вопросов про unity ? Я что-то ни одного не заметил беглым взглядом даже по http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity+-unity3d

Comment: @NickVolynkin для убунтовского юнити лучше использовать [tag:ubuntu-unity] как на SO

Comment: @Nofate а это идея.

Comment: Есть же ещё Unity dependency injection container. Для него метка тоже нужна.

Answer (score -3):

## Переименовать [unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) в [unity2d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2d)

Эти метки будут относиться только к вопросам по 2d играм.